# How to i convert this python code to dart?

Tags: python, string, dart, immutability

**How to convert this code to dart**

```
python:
querystr.strip ('[]'). strip ('()'). rstrip (','). strip ('' ')
```

**python strip Definition and Usage**

- The strip() method removes any leading (spaces at the beginning) and
  trailing (spaces at the end) characters (space is the default leading
  character to remove)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check String trailing and leading with .startsWith() and .endsWith() and perform substring like this:

```
void main() {
  print(strip(strip(strip(strip(strip(" [(,'Sample String',)] ", " "), "[]"), "()"), ","), "''"));
  //Output: "Sample String"
}

String strip(String string, String char)
{  
  string = (string.startsWith(char[0]) && string.endsWith(char[char.length - 1])) 
  ? (){string = string.substring(1);
    string = string.substring(0, string.length - 1); return string;}() 
  : string;

  return string;
}
```

Or, You can use regular expression like this:

```
void main() {
  print(strip(strip(strip(strip(strip(" [(,'Sample String',)] ", " "), "[]"), "()"), ","), "''"));
  //Output: "Sample String"
}

String strip(String string, String char)
{
  char = char.length == 1 ? "$char$char" : char; // For single character
  String lc = char[0]; // Extract leading character
  String tc = char[1]; // Extract trailing character


  String l = "^\\$lc+"; // Regex for Leading character: <lc>
  String t = "\\$tc+\$"; // Regex for Trailing character <tc>

  // Replace Leading and Trailing sequence match with blank
  return string.replaceAll(new RegExp(l), "").replaceAll(new RegExp(t), "");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For `dart` you can use `trim()` method of the `String` class. This method removes the leading and trailing spaces. See the documentation: https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.7.0/dart-core/String/trim.html

And, remember, in `dart` as in many other languages I know, strings are **immutable**. You cannot modify but you can make a certain operation and assign the result to a new string.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

```dart
extension StringExtension on String {
  String stip(List regs, String replaces) {
    var ss;
    for (int i = 0; i <= regs.length; i++) {
     ss = this.replaceAll(regs[i], replaces);
    }
    return ss;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add some context to explain how this will answer the question, instead of code-only answer